# How do I tell pandas to parse a particular column as a datetime object, but not make it an index?

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, pandas

I have a csv file where one of the columns is a date/time string.  How do I parse it correctly with `pandas`?  I don't want to make that column the index.  Thanks!

Uri

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass `dateutil.parser.parse` (or another datetime conversion function) in the `converters` argument to `read_csv`